# Website times out sporadically: ERR_TIMED_OUT and can't ssh into instance with nginx and EC2 setup

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timeout

I am running a django app with nginx as webserver on an EC2 instance. The website gets a decent amount of API calls per minute depending on how many testpipelines I run. My problem is that the website times out sporadically. I can't reach it in the browswer and all my tests fail of course. Also I can't login to my instance anymore but have to wait until it is back up.... SHouldn't I at least be able ssh into it even though the website times out??

Now I am wondering: Is that rather an nginx configuration error or could it be that my EC2 does not have enough memory? I am deploying to an t2 micro instance on EC2 which has 1 vCPU and also only 1GB of memory. Let's say I get 20-30 API calls, all trying to download files between 10 and 50 MB. Do I need a bigger instance or should it be no problem to handle for the EC2?

Or could it be my nginx configuration? Right now I use this (I am not at all an nginx expert, please tell me if there are stupid configs set):

main config

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay    on;
    send_timeout       90;
    keepalive_timeout  90;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    client_body_timeout 120;
    client_body_buffer_size 128K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    client_header_timeout 120;
    client_max_body_size 5G;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_min_length 512;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And server config

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.de;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    charset utf-8;
    ssl_stapling off;
    ssl_stapling_verify off;

    ssl_certificate            /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.de/privkey.pem;


    set $my_host $http_host;
    if ($http_host = "mywebsite.de") {
          set $my_host "mywebsite.de";
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600; 
  }

}

server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name mywebsite.de;
        return 301 https://mywebsite.de$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name www.mywebsite.de;
        return 301 https://mywebsite.de$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ;
        server_name www.mywebsite.de;
        return 301 https://mywebsite.de$request_uri;
        ssl_stapling off;
        ssl_stapling_verify off;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.de/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.de/privkey.pem;
}
```

It could also be something else, but what else could crash my machine? Maybe Redis? I am not sure. I am looking for possible reasons this could happen and for possible solutions to have this as stable as possible.

Very grateful to the community for any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not responding to ssh is unusual - there was a similar question here recently, you might be able to find it. I would want to see the CloudWatch information about CPU usage, CPU credit, RAM usage (custom metric, google it), swap usage at 1 minute intervals or better. Monit (software you install) may also be able to do that if you can't use Cloudwatch. When you say "wait until it's back up" what exactly do you mean - do you reboot, does it start working randomly, does it start working after tests finish, etc. You can also just try your software on a large m5 instance to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response Tim. "Wait until it's back up" actually means that I had to reboot it to get it working again. Yes I think I will try to run it on a larger instance. I will provide more information, but unfortunately I don't have Cloud Watch attached now. But I will post some screenshots with the info I have and try to get my hands on more. Thanks again! But do you think this has nothing to do with nginx and rather something with EC2? I just want to avoid poking holes into my nginx config if that seems unneccassary...

Comment: oh wait maybe I can provide cloud watch info

Comment: CloudWatch gathers hypervisor statistics such as CPU usage and CPU credits automatically, but you need to install an agent or script to get OS level metrics like RAM used. That you have to reboot to get SSH back seems odd. First thing before you post screenshots is to try some things out yourself, like a larger instance size, connecting CloudWatch and gathering RAM usage information, so that if you come back you can give more information. Nginx can't crash the OS. If it crashes change the security group to prevent web traffic and see if it recovers enough you can SSH in.

Comment: Ok I will deploy to a larger instance and gather more information and come back here. Thanks very much! But let's say this is a problem with the EC2 instance,  then I don't have many other options than using a larger instance, I assume, right?

Comment: Depends what is happening. You could check syslog to see why it becomes unresponsive. If it's RAM you could potentially add swap, if it doesn't slow it down too much. You could auto scale out with on demand or spot instances during high load periods. But if a larger server fixes it sometimes it's cheaper to pay the bill than to set everything else up.